# How to modify the cell value of a table in an pptx file with apache-poi 3.9?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to modify the cell value of a table within a pptx file.
Saving the file, the modification is not applied.

Here is the used code:

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:/Report_Template.pptx");
XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(is);
is.close();

ppt.getPageSize();
for(XSLFSlide slide : ppt.getSlides()) {
    for(XSLFShape shape : slide){
        shape.getAnchor();
        if (shape instanceof XSLFTable){
            XSLFTable t = (XSLFTable) shape;
            List<XSLFTableRow> r = t.getRows();
            for (int i = 1; i < r.size(); i++) {
                String text = r.get(i).getCells().get(1).getText();
                if(text.contains("#ID")) {
                    r.get(i).getCells().get(1).setText("20131028152343");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:/Report.pptx");
ppt.write(out);
out.close();
```

The file `C:/Report.pptx` does not contain the string "20131028152343" but "#ID".
Could someone help me?

Comment: Are you sure that your if statement is being triggered? What happens if you print out the value of `text` as your code runs, do you see the text you expect?

Comment: @Gagravarr I am facing the same problem. And yes, the if statement is triggered and calling getText() after setText() returns the right value.

Comment: If you write the file out, then read it back in again with Apache POI, does POI see the changed text? i.e. is the problem with POI not writing the text to the file, or with POI writing it in a way that PowerPoint doesn't notice?

Comment: No, it doesn't, so it looks like it does not write the changes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with tables (with POI 3.10): I could not modify them, and sometimes, the file was corrupted (I could not open it with LibreOffice).

I have just replaced the jar `poi-ooxml-schemas-*.jar` with `ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar` (you can find it on Maven Central) in my build path, and it works now.

Comment: Thanks! Replacing the poi-ooxml-schemas-*.jar with ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar worked.