# How to update a XSLFTable (table in .pptx presentation) using Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint, xslf

I'm working with Apache POI and I'm trying to automate some tasks with Powerpoint reports. More precisely, I would like to update the data inside a .pptx presentation from code, including tables.

I've managed to get the XSLFTable objects (thanks to this page : [How to modify the cell value of a table in an pptx file with apache-poi 3.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975379/how-to-modify-the-cell-value-of-a-table-in-an-pptx-file-with-apache-poi-3-9)), but now I'm trying to update the table structure.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to create or remove rows (or columns) in that table. The method `getRows` returns a list, but it seems unmodifiable. There is a `addRow` method, but I didn't find anything to delete/remove rows.

Do you know how I can achieve that?

Thanks a lot, and best regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Get XSLFTable**

```
XSLFTable t = null;
for (XSLFShape shape : slide) {
    if (shape instanceof XSLFTable) {
        t = (XSLFTable) shape;
        r = t.getRows();
   }
}
```

**Add Row and Cell**

```
XSLFTableRow titleRow = tbl.addRow();
titleRow.setHeight(50);
XSLFTableCell titleCell1 = titleRow.addCell();
XSLFTextParagraph p1 = titleCell1.addNewTextParagraph();
p1.setTextAlign(TextAlign.CENTER);
XSLFTextRun r1 = p1.addNewTextRun();
r1.setText("Column title");
r1.setBold(true);
r1.setFontColor(new Color(0, 104, 145));
titleCell1.setFillColor(new Color(190, 230, 245));
r1.setFontSize(25.0);
titleCell1.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
```

**Remove Row**

```
t.getCTTable().getTrList().remove(t.getNumberOfRows()-1); //Remove the last row from table.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm not familiar with the underlying CT* objects, but your code is clear :)

Comment: By the way, could you please tell me more about the `shape.getAnchor();` line? Why do we need it?

Comment: Sorry. That line was added accidentally. Not required in this scenario.

Comment: Hi Gilsha, I'm come here at 2021 and has some question related to this.
How can I add a XSLFTable row to the end and KEEP THE FORMAT as the last row?

When I call `table.addRow()`, it will give me a new row with fresh format with no fill color, font, font size.

In MS Powerpoint, I can just click on 'Insert Row', and a new row will be added with the same format as the last row.